# Which is faster in Objective-C, to assign or to test?

Tags: objective-c

```
BOOL bSomeBool;
```

Which is faster in Objective-c, to assign or to test?

```
bSomeBool= NO;
```

or

```
if(bSomeBool)
{
}
```

instead. Looking for every bit of savings I can get.

EDIT:
The reason I'm asking is that I'm doing this

```
if(bSomeBool)
{
    bSomeBool= NO;
}
```

in my drawing code a couple of times, so I was wondering whether I should just do this

```
bSomeBool= NO;
```

instead. Looking for as much savings as I can get.

Comment: you assign when you have to assign. You test when you have to test. Period.

Comment: I think it's a legitimate, if not terribly interesting question. I sometimes think the same thing myself in instances where I can either make several assignments unconditionally, or use a single conditional to skip the assignments if the predicate guarantees that the assignments are unnecessary or redundant. I never end up worrying too much about it in the end though, because unless I'm doing a large number of redundant or unnecessary calculations, there's not likely to be any noticeable improvement in performance either way.

Comment: premature optimization, this code is by far not something you have to worry at all, I don't think there's any gain, you're changing one operation for one or two in some cases, so, if anything, you're losing performance

Comment: Why are you looking for every bit of savings you can get? You'll save a lot more by targeting the parts of your program that are actually slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving a single instruction in drawing code will be like pouring a thimble full of water from the Titanic as she breaks up and heads to Davy Jones.

It will not make any difference. If you want to optimize, draw less and use core animation more.